# VM Ware Question

Tags: 16.04, virtualization, vmware, kali

Wondering what the best vmware solution is best for running on unbuntu 16.04 to run Kali? Any feedback would be helpful still fairly new to unbuntu.

Comment: I am unsure if you literally want to use VMWare or looking for any Ubuntu compatible VM ? If the latter is true then I use Oracle VirtualBox on Ubuntu 18.04 and you can install Kali on VirtualBox guest with Ubuntu as the host machine no problem as per the following instructions:

https://phoenixnap.com/kb/how-to-install-kali-linux-on-virtualbox

I  Installed VirtualBox following the instructions on the website, however the installation has been simplified since I last installed it, you'll find the latest installation instructions here: https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/VBoxInstallAndRun

Answer (score 0):

Terminology: a Virtual Machine Monitor (**VMM**) is software that lets you run Virtual Machines (**VMs**). Examples of VMMs include VMware, VirtualBox, parallels, KVM, qemu.

If you just want to get into Kali without stuffing around, I would probably recommend VirtualBox with this [pre-packaged kali image](https://www.offensive-security.com/kali-linux-vm-vmware-virtualbox-image-download/).

If you want to learn a bit more then you can install Kali in VMWare using an ISO image (basically a virtual DVD.)

KVM tends to have better performance than VirtualBox especially with concurrent VMs. Although installing KVM is a pain, once set up I had a flawless experience in Kali.

Comment: Thank you!I'll look into KVM!